"grub-reboot" equivalent for rEFInd?
In GRUB2, you can use grub-reboot to temporarily set the default boot option to another OS for a single boot, allowing you to switch OSes without having to stand by the computer, wait for POST, and press keys.
Is there an equivalent operation for rEFInd so I can remotely reboot my PC into Windows without locking that as the default until I get home?

Note the low number of watchers for your tag(s). Try to find some other  appropriate tags with higher numbers of watchers. Maybe include a tag for your underlying OS (unix|linux (not both!) ).
